# Get Title and Published Date of All posts published in Blogger Site using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

How can i use **`Invoke-WebRequest`** to get all blogs posted till date in a blogger website?? can anyone help me out?

i did all this stuff but was not able to get output

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "www.vinithmenon.com"
$r
$r.AllElements
$r.AllElements | gm
$r.AllElements.innerhtml[0]
$new = $r.AllElements
$new
$new.innerhtml
$new.innerhtml[0]
$new | gm
$new.outerhtml | select -First 1
$new.outerhtml | select -First 1 | gm
$new.innerhtml | select -First 1 | gm
$new | gm
$new | select tagname |select -First 1
$new | select innertext |select -First 1
$new.innertext |select -First 1
$new | gm
$new.innerhtml |select -First 1
$new.innerhtml |select -First 1 | gm
$new | gm
$new.outerhtml |select -First 1 | gm
$new | gm
$new.tagname |select -First 1 | gm
```

Comment: What version of powershell? In v3.0 you can try this: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/03/channel-9s-mms-2013-rss-feed-is-more-fun-with-powershell/

Comment: its powershell v3, i tried it but no luck, also tried  Invoke-RestMethod

Comment: where's your RSS feed? you probably need to point it at that

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://www.vinithmenon.com/feeds/posts/default?m=1" | select -ExpandProperty title still gives me only a few post titles

Comment: I've not been through the full list but when I try `Invoke-RestMethod http://www.vinithmenon.com/feeds/posts/default | select -expand title` I get the correct titles (at least the first and last match the first and last on the feed page I get in IE10).  Are you sure Blogger isn't applying a paging filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave me all the results Finally

```
PS C:\Users\Vinith> ([xml](invoke-webrequest 'http://www.vinithmenon.com/feeds/posts/default')).feed.entry.title.'#text'
 | Measure-Object


Count    : 25

PS C:\Users\Vinith> ([xml](invoke-webrequest 'http://www.vinithmenon.com/feeds/posts/default')).feed.entry.title.'#text'

Presenting at PowerShell Bangalore User Group Meeting, June 1st 2013
Provision Virtual Machines in Parallel using New Workflow Feature in PowerShell V3
Running SharePoint 2010 PowerShell  cmdlets on Windows Server 2012
Convert a Windows Server 2012 Server to iSCSI Target Server And Offer Low-Cost Storage
PowerShell Script to Check if Windows 8 PC is complaint to run Hyper-V V-3
New iSCSI cmdlets in PowerShell V3 Part - 1
Delegated Administration in Windows PowerShell v3
Switching Over From PowerShell V2 to V3 in Same PowerShell Console
Setting Default Parameters using $PSDefaultParameterValues in PowerShell V3
Ordered Hash Tables in Windows PowerShell V3.
New CIM Cmdlets in PowerShell V3
PowerShell WebAccess, Web-Based Windows PowerShell Console
Unblock Files Using PowerShell v3 "Unblock-File" cmdlet
Converting between GUI and Server Core in Windows Server 2012 Using PowerShell V3
Manipulating SharePoint Lists using PowerShell
Set Permissions on a File or Directory using PowerShell
Using Performance Counter with PowerShell to Extract Server Uptime
Customizing PowerShell Prompt via $Profile
PowerShell Script to Automate Virtual Machine Provisioning using Hyper-V Version 3 Cmdlets in Windows Server 2012
  PowerShell Script to configure iSCSI Network Cards as per Microsoft Best Practices.
PowerShell V3 Scheduled Job to start iSCSI service for Hyper-V Server
PowerShell Script for Automated Install of Hyper-V Integration Services in a VM running on Windows Server 2012 with Hyp
er-V V 3.0 Role using PowerShell Remoting
Get VM Creation Metrics Using SCVMM PowerShell Cmdlets
Extract MPIO.SYS and MSISCSI.SYS File Information across Virtual Machine's and Hyper-V Hosts Using PowerShell SCVMM Cmd
lets
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a wrong URL. Look at the RSS feed URL.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://www.vinithmenon.com/feeds/posts/default
```

Now, explore the properties like title, etc

Comment: gives me only a few titles, even tried this 
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://www.vinithmenon.com/feeds/posts/default?m=1" | select -ExpandProperty title

Comment: it is a property of your blog rss feed and nothing to do with PowerShell. You need to check your blog settings to allow complete list of your posts